# stream video from pc to webpage

Tags: javascript, stream, webcam, vlc, webrtc

I want to stream my webcam to my website. Maybe inside < video >, < embed >, or even < img > tag.
What would be the best way? I've tried VLC-player and webrtc.
The problem with VLC is that I cannot manage to stream outside my LAN. Inside my LAN it is working fine, but I cannot connect through the internet. And I also don't know how to implement it to my website.
The problem with webrtc is that it is not supported by ios. It works fine on windows and android, but is failing to run on iphones and ipads (I didn't tried it on mac, but I think it will work).
Maybe there is some code in javascript, html or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iOS devices, webrtc is ***not fully supported***. However, you [CAN build the Native C/C++ API](http://ninjanetic.com/how-to-get-started-with-webrtc-and-ios-without-wasting-10-hours-of-your-life/) for them and build a [locally running applications](https://github.com/gandg/webrtc-ios) that can access your stream(not from a webpage but currently your only option on iOS).

OSX, Windows, and Android's versions of Chrome should all work well together(I have tested this myself and have gotten streams to work between all those devices without issue) and access you stream.

For grabbing your camera's stream, you could grab it through chrome, continually stream and dynamically handle peer connections as they come in from your signalling server(you can use the same local stream for numerous peer connections). You could also use a natively built application using the [WebRTC API](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/) but that will be more complex than manipulating your stream in chrome.